# How to evaluate this integral using complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate the following integral using complex analysis methods.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}$$
I know how to solve it using the trigonometric substitution $x=\tan(y)\implies dx=\frac{dy}{\cos^2(y)}$ and the final result is $2$, but how can I solve this using complex analysis?

Comment: Without actually having calculated it: the integrand is symmetric wrt to the y-axis, so the integral is just half of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx$. Now use the standard method using the residue of the integrand to calculate that integral.

Comment: Use a semicircular contour in the upper half plane. You will have a pole at $i$ which you will need to calculate the residue at. You will also need to show that as the radius of the contour gets very large, the contribution from the curved part gets negligibly small.

Comment: I'll tell you for free (fill in the details!) that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)^p}\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(p-1/2)}{\Gamma(p)}$$
And the integral converges if $\operatorname{Re}(p)>1/2$.

Comment: The integral on $[0,\,\infty)$ is $1$; the integral on $(-\infty,\,\infty)$ is $2$.

Comment: Yeah, I've edited. But what is the order of the pole at z=i @K.defaoite?

Comment: In fact, it is not that easy to integrate this function in the complex plane. The problem is that the points $x=\pm i$ are not the poles, but the branch points, and we have to add a cut linking, for example, these points the make a closed contour. The program is doable, but the easiest way is just to make the change $t=\frac{1}{x^2}$, and the integral becomes $\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{2(1+t)^\frac{3}{2}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}\Big|_0^\infty=1$